# Share value from database in all view in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel. I'm trying to create a simple app with some variable that shouold be in every view. So I create a setting model, with many fields and a unique slug field. Now to share this variable from database I've created a middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $site_settings = Cache::remember('settings', 60, function() {
        return Setting::all();
    });

    view()->share('site_settings', $site_settings);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Now to show this variable in view I have:

```
{{{ $site_settings->get(0)->value }}}
```

This works great, but I'd like to have a more intuitive code in my view, accessing the setting by slug. Something like:

```
{{{ $site_settings->findBySlug("MYVARIABLE")->value }}}
```

So it's possible to filter collection by an unique slug?

Comment: you can use facade `View::share('data', [1, 2, 3])` http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views

Comment: The way I understand this is you're using middleware to get data passed to the view? Perhaps you should be using something else? Have you looked at service injection for view: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection

Comment: @haakym this seems a good solution, but could I inject model? also, with this approach I should make one or more query to database on each request, without caching doesn't seems a valid solution....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Info:

This assumes your settings table structure is as following:

```
----------------------
| id |  key  | value |
----------------------
|  1 | title |  foo  |
|  2 |  asd  |  bar  |
|  3 |  qqq  |  zzz  |
----------------------
```

## Steps

**Step 1:** Put the following `newCollection` method into **App\Setting** model:

```
class Settings extends ... {
    public function newCollection(array $models = array())
    {
        return new \App\Collections\SettingsCollection($models);
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Put the following lines into **App\Collections\SettingsCollection** class:

```
<?php namespace App\Collections;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class SettingsCollection extends Collection {

    public function get($name, $default = null)
    {
        return array_first($this->items, function($itemKey, $model) use ($name)
        {
            return $model->key == $name;
        }, $default)->value;
    }

}
```

**Step 3: Enjoy!** This is the collection I'm currently using. **Instead of this:**

```
$settings = Setting::all();
$settings->where('key', 'key_name')->first()->value;
```

**You can simply just do this:**

```
$settings = Setting::all();
echo $settings->get('key_name'); // returns value of the setting with the key 'title'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a query scope would fit.

In your model:

```
public function scopeFindBySlug($slug){
    return $query->where('slug','=', $slug);
}
```

So you will have: `$site_settings->findBySlug('your_slug')->get();`